# To update Point location every 1 second

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, python-2.7

I am using update cursor to change the location of a point with FID = 0 every second, but whenever I run the code my ArcGIS freezes and point doesnot move. I am visualizing an output where the point move vertically from (-74.668,-100) to (-74.668,100). Here is my sample code:

```
import time
import arcpy
#my workspace is set to a folder containing "WorldPoint.shp"
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("WorldPoint",("SHAPE@XY",),'"'+'FID"'+' = 0') as cursor:
     for row in cursor:
         for i in range(-100,100,1):
             yvalue = i
             row[0] = (float(-74.668),float(yvalue))
             cursor.updateRow(row)
             arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
             time.sleep(1)
```

I am new to Python 2.7.

Comment: I'd make I loop the 1st.

Comment: Because you've not left your cursor it has had no chance to clean up after itself.

Comment: At 111 km/sec, your object is travelling more than 14 times the orbital velocity of the International Space Station, and ten times faster than the escape velocity of Earth. ArcGIS has an extension that supports realtime event objects, called Tracking Analyst. Trying to update shapefiles every second isn't something I've had to try since ArcView 2.1 days (and it caused application failure due to filesystem race conditions every few minutes). Starting at 10 degrees below the South Pole won't help, stability wise, even if you flushed the values to disk.

Comment: Is this any python code as a workaround, without using tracking analyst

Answer (score 1):

Create a new cursor for each interval.

```
for i in range(-100,100,1):
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("WorldPoint",("SHAPE@XY",),'"'+'FID"'+' = 0') as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            row[0] = (float(-74.668),float(i))
            cursor.updateRow(row)
    arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
    time.sleep(1)
```

You probably want to apply your SQL query outside of your cursor if it's a large data set.

Comment: I tried this code, but ArcMap got stuck as before.

Comment: How many records does your WorldPoint layer have?

Comment: just one record

Comment: It's a 10.1 thing. I tested on my 10.1 and the code didn't work. It works on my 10.4 machine.

Comment: is there any way to make this code work on arc 10.1